# Compare each item in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects:

```
   const array = [{ 
    "colour": "red",
    "job": "student",
    "title": "Mr",
},
 {​
    "colour": "green",
    "job": "student",
    "title": "",
},
{​
    "colour": "",
    "job": "teacher",
    "title": "Mr",
},  
{​
    "colour": "red",
    "job": "student",
    "title": "Mr",
}}]
```

I would like to compare the objects inside the array with each other.

What I have so far does not seem efficient as I would be comparing index `i=1` and `j=2` and `i=2` and `j=1` which is comparing exactly the same object. I am using Lodash `_.isEqual()` to compare the objects.

```
 const handleArrayItems = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (j === i) {
                continue; //to avoid comparing same object
            }
            if (_.isEqual(array[j],array[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }   
 };
```

Based on what is returned from above, it is passed into an if/else statement.

```
if (handleArrayItems()) {
  console.log("found a duplicate item in array")
}
```

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: `handleArrayItems()` will return true if there is a match and false is no object items are the same

Answer (score 1):

Separate objects are not equal to each other.

```
if (_.isEqual(array[j] === array[i])) {
```

will evaluate the argument first:

```
array[j] === array[i]
```

which is `false`, resulting in:

```
if (_.isEqual(false)) {
```

which doesn't work.

You need to pass both values to `isEqual` for comparison

```
if (_.isEqual(array[j], array[i])) {
```

so that Lodash can compare the values itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make `j` goes from `i+1` to `array.length` to doing comparison twice.

And `i` can go to `length-1` only, since `j` will go to the end.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++) {
    for (let j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
```